# Use Apex: page messages with Java script remoting

Tags: apex, javascript-remoting, error-messages, page-messages

I am using javascript remoting in my VF page.
I want to display any excpetion coming in Remoting as Apex page messages .

Any direct way I can do that?

Thanks,

Ray

Comment: Any answer guys..???